# concurrency management in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to convert my code from Linq-to-SQL into Entity Framework 6. I noticed that concurrency management options in Entity Framework are quite 'Limited'.

**Question**: what is the equivalent `ConflictMode.ContinueOnConflict` and `ConflictMode.FailOnFirstConflict` in Entity Framework? How can I just try to save all changes at once in db and collect all conflicts later? As far as I've learnt, there seems to be no direct way in EF or am I missing something?

More specifically, how would I change this code to EF6 style?

```
try
{
    storage.Accounts.InsertAllOnSubmit(newAccountsList);
    storage.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.ContinueOnConflict);
}
catch (ChangeConflictException)
{
    var failedItems = storage.ChangeConflicts;
    foreach (var failedItem in failedItems)
    {
        failedItem.Resolve(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues);
    }
}
catch (KeyViolationException)
{
    // Here I'm doing nothing
}

storage.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.FailOnFirstConflict);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Getting no clues on this.

Comment: Did you ever find any type of solution to this? I am in the same boat right now.

Comment: when game gets hard..